TypeScript Error TS2769 with useQuery - Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter
I'm encountering an issue with useQuery in my TypeScript React project. Here's the code:
export const useGetMovieList = () =>
    useQuery(['fetchMovies'], () => fetchMovies());

This results in the following error:
ERROR in src/hooks/useGetMovieList.tsx:4:47
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(options: DefinedInitialDataOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>, queryClient?: QueryClient | undefined): DefinedUseQueryResult<unknown, Error>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DefinedInitialDataOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>'.
      Property 'queryKey' is missing in type 'string[]' but required in type 'UseQueryOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(options: UndefinedInitialDataOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>, queryClient?: QueryClient | undefined): UseQueryResult<unknown, Error>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UndefinedInitialDataOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>'.
      Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'UseQueryOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(options: UseQueryOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>, queryClient?: QueryClient | undefined): UseQueryResult<unknown, Error>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UseQueryOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>'.
      Property 'queryKey' is missing in type 'string[]' but required in type 'UseQueryOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>'.

However, in another project, I have a very similar piece of code that works fine:
export const useGetLogout = () =>
  useQuery(['logout'], () => getLogout);

This works without any issues. I'm wondering what might be wrong with my useGetMovieList code. Is there a difference in how I'm handling the useQuery key or options?
Would appreciate any help or insight!
export const useGetMovieList = () =>
    useQuery({
        queryKey: ['fetchMovies'],
        queryFn: fetchMovies
    });

This method works well, but I want to follow the code method of the project I referenced.

The project you're referencing is likely using an older version of the react-query library, specifically v3 or earlier.
In v3 of the react-query library, useQuery hook's signature accepted 3 arguments: queryKey, queryFn and optional config.
useQuery("queryKey", () => {}, options)

See v3 useQuery documentation
Starting from v4, the useQuery hook now expects only a single argument. This is an object that contains queryKey and queryFn as parameters.
useQuery({
  queryKey: "queryKey",
  queryFn: () => {},
  ...rest
})

See latest useQuery documentation.
I would suggest using the latest library as it will have the latest features and fixes.
If you need to use v3, the library moved to a new NPM package between v3 and v4. See their v3 package here.
